# TextMate-Like Bundle Functionality for Vim

Tags: vim, textmate, textmatebundles

I know Vim Snippets ( Using snippets.vim ) but is there something like Bundles ( or something to emulate it ) for vim

Comment: Aren't bundles just what they call plugins?  What [specific bundle](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/) are you wanting to emulate?

Comment: For me its just the ease of creating Bundles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for "pathogen": http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332. It lets you put entire plugins in their own directory under "~/.vim/bundle".

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).